# How to check Django permissions in Vue JS template

Tags: django, vue.js, permissions

I would like to `v-show` a label based on a Django permission, like so:

```
<label for="input"
       class="ui right floated icon button" :class="color"
       v-show="(!is_existing) && {{perms.auth.has_permission}}">
    <i class="file text icon"></i>
    'Upload'
</label>
```

However, Vue JS complains because `Property or method "False" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.`.

Is there a way to access the permission inside `v-show`?

Comment: you can try to use tag lower `v-show="(!is_existing) && {{perms.auth.has_permission|lower}}">`

Comment: That works, feel free to create an answer!

Comment: glad to help you

Comment: @Darkstarone how you access perms in vue js ? can you tell me how to use django permissions in vue js ?

Comment: @AjinkyaBhosale Django permissions work the same regardless of framework, if you have access to the template you can just use `{{perms.auth.*}}` like I did above, If you're seperated from Django (e.g. serving a seperate frontend from an API) you'll have to pass the permissions along via the API.

Comment: @Darkstarone I want to separate front end and backend. I have created API using Django Rest Framework and I am creating front end using vuejs. 
Previously In django templates ,  I show menu's in base.html like follows          
`{% if perms.cms.view_village %}
                     <li><a href="{% url 'village' %}">Village Master</a></li>
                 {% endif %} `

How can I do same in front end ( vuejs ) ?

Comment: You'll need to package up the Django permissions object into an API call via the Rest Framework (e.g. make a ListView which uses Auth.Permissions as kit's queryset), then you can call the permissions via the API and load them into a Javascript variable. 

Alternatively you could have an API method which checks if a permission string exists for a user.

Comment: @Darkstarone Okay. Thank you. I will do it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in js the boolean true is in lowercase but in the python start from capitalize, so you can try to use tag [lower](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#lower)

```
v-show="(!is_existing) && {{perms.auth.has_permission|lower}}">
```